# ¿Cuál es el sujeto en la oración "mañana lluvia caerá"?

Tags: sintaxis, sujeto

Según me explicaron en otra pregunta aquí, *hoy* puede ser sujeto de una oración, y creo que si la oración fuera "mañana llueve", *mañana* sería el sujeto (corrijame si me equivoco).

Pero ¿qué pasa cuando la oración es "Mañana lluvia caerá"? Es *mañana* o es *lluvia* el sujeto?

¿Qué función sintáctica tiene la palabra que no es el sujeto en esa oración? Porque si a la frase le invertimos el orden y queda "Mañana caerá lluvia", *mañana* sería el sujeto, ¿cierto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Llover" es en general un verbo impersonal. Sólo ocasionalmente puede recibir un sujeto, como en:

- Le llovieron felicitaciones / ofertas de trabajo. (donde "felicitaciones"/"ofertas de trabajo" es sujeto)

"Mañana llueve" no tiene sujeto: es una oración impersonal.

En cambio, en "Mañana caerá lluvia" (una oración poco feliz), "lluvia" es sujeto de "caerá".

"Mañana" es, en todos los casos, circunstancial de tiempo.

Comment: En "Le llovieron felicitaciones", "felicitaciones" no seria el complemento directo (CD)?, aun es parte del predicado. Nunca he visto que una oracion con verbo impersonal aceptara sujeto. En este caso, segun el espanol que di en la escuela,  felicitaciones seria lo llovido, que responde a CD, y nadie puede ejecutar la accion de llover.

Comment: @Theia "llover" nunca es transitivo y no puede recibir CD. Puede ser impersonal o intransitivo. Dicho en lenguaje llano, el CD es el objeto que "recibe" la acción, y no podemos decir que las felicitaciones fueron llovidas. La prueba que haces es engañosa. Si yo digo: "Ocurrió un accidente", "un accidente" es sujeto aunque sea "lo ocurrido". La prueba para confirmar que se trata de un CD consiste en poder reemplazarlo por *lo/la/s*: En "La lluvia mojó los campos", "los campos" es CD porque puedo decir "La lluvia LOS mojó".

Comment: Otra comprobación posible es la conversión en pasiva: "Los campos fueron mojados por la lluvia." Ninguna de estas pruebas funciona con "Llovieron elogios": *Los llovieron / *Elogios fueron llovidos.

Comment: Si, tienes razon, tambien vi sobre esto aqui http://www.asmadrid.org/spanish/depto/gram/Imperson.htm#meteo, gracias por la aclaracion :)